# Why are archived pages showing up in searches and able to be accessed?

Tags: search

I'm new to wordpress. Archived pages are showing up. 
First , where are they found in the admin?

Second, why would this be happening?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "archived pages"? Do you mean pages that you have set as private, or archives that list groups of posts?

Comment: My apologies, I've rephrased the question.

Comment: You haven't clarified. What do you mean by "Archived pages"?